# asp.net updateing webpage on database update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web, oledb

Hi I am working on a website using c# that requires a voting system.

My database table looks like this

Objects_tb:

```
ID | name | votes

1 | Object1 | 5

2 | Object2 | 3

3 | Object3 | 0
```

I need to show how much people voted for each object. The best way I found so far is to call an update method every certain time, but I would like if I could update the vote number shown in the webpage only if someone voted.

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to a gridview on page load.

If you need to update every so often, throw it in an update panel with a timer asyncpostback trigger

On Async postback check the values returned from the database, if they are different then rebind the datagrid